# Trying to change Data in Database with DataTable in Visual Basic

Tags: database, vb.net, datatable

i'm trying to use DataTables and a .mdb Database on Visual Basic 2010 for the following functions, but it doenst work:

I have an existing .mdb-Database with a Table "Daten" and with named Columns in this Table.
And i'd like to add a new row with new informations to the database.
So i'm connection to the Database with the following code:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Daten"

            Dim connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

            Try
                connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" & pfad_netzdb
            Catch e As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message)
            End Try
            Dim adapter As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection)
```

After that, i'm filling a DataTable with the given datas of the database:

```
Dim daten As New DataTable

            adapter.Fill(daten)
```

After that, i'd like to add a Row to the DataTable and fill the Row with new Informations:

```
daten.Rows.Add()
daten.Rows(daten.Rows.Count - 1)(0) = "kdjfk"
daten.Rows(daten.Rows.Count - 1)(1) = "dkjfk"
daten.Rows(daten.Rows.Count - 1)(2) = "kdjfkd"
```

After that, i'd like to send my changed DataTable with the new row and the new Informations in the row back to the database. I think here is the point where my code doesn't do what i'm expecting. I'm trying it like this, but it doenst work:

```
adapter.Update(daten)
```

Can anyone help my why this Code doesn't work?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: Please provide  _"Code doesn't work"_ with content.

Comment: What are you doing with this line "daten.Rows.Count - 1"

Answer (score 0):

Have you provided the `InsertCommand`? You can use a `CommandBuilder`.

```
Dim conString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & "Data Source=" & pfad_netzdb
Using connection As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(conString)
    Using adapter = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Daten", connection)
        Dim builder = New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(adapter)
        builder.GetInsertCommand()
        Dim daten As New DataTable
        daten.Columns.Add("ColumnName1", GetType(String)) ' provide the correct name+type '
        daten.Columns.Add("ColumnName2", GetType(String)) ' provide the correct name+type '
        daten.Columns.Add("ColumnName3", GetType(String)) ' provide the correct name+type '
        Dim newRow = daten.Rows.Add()
        newRow(0) = "kdjfk"
        newRow(1) = "dkjfk"
        newRow(2) = "kdjfkd"
        connection.Open()
        adapter.Update(daten)
    End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use parameterized way to insert records

```
Dim adapter As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter()
Dim command As OleDbCommand

' Create the SelectCommand.
command = New OleDbCommand("SELECT * from Daten", connection)

adapter.SelectCommand = command

' Create the InsertCommand.
command = New OleDbCommand( _
    "INSERT INTO Daten(ColumnName1, ColumnName2,ColumnName3) " & _
    "VALUES (?, ?,?)", connection)

command.Parameters.Add( _
    "ColumnName1", OleDbType.VarChar, 40, "kdjfk") //Replace with correct column name and data type
command.Parameters.Add( _
    "ColumnName2", OleDbType.VarChar, 40, "dkjfk") //Replace with correct column name and data type
command.Parameters.Add( _
    "ColumnName3", OleDbType.VarChar, 40, "kdjfkd")//Replace with correct column name and data type

adapter.InsertCommand = command
Return adapter
```